# Finding the first index of every distinct value in CUDA array

Tags: cuda, thrust

Assume we have an array like this:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, ...
```

I would like to have the index of every first occurrence of every value, so in this example [0, 3, 4, 7, 9]. The array is sorted and all possible values are known and consecutive.

Possible solutions I have is using a kernel for every element in this array and use an atomicmin to save the lowest index. But I assume a better approach is possible.

Comment: Compare each value to the one preceding it to figure whether it's the first occurence.

Comment: How does your array appear as the input? If it is read from external source (e.g. a file) then you need a separate kernel for this. But, if it is an output of another kernel, say - a sorting algorithm - then it may be better to obtain the desired output at that time, rather than in the separate step.

Comment: It's the output of multiple thrust calls, so a separate step is desirable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a single call to `thrust::unique_by_key()` if you provide a vector of indices e.g. via `thrust::sequence()`.  Here's a worked example:

```
$ cat t3.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/unique.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  int keys[] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4};
  int ks = sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_keys(keys, keys+ks);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_result(ks);
  thrust::sequence(d_result.begin(), d_result.end());
  int rs  = (thrust::unique_by_key(d_keys.begin(), d_keys.end(), d_result.begin())).first - d_keys.begin();
  thrust::copy_n(d_result.begin(), rs, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t3 t3.cu
$ ./t3
0,3,4,7,9,
$
```

The important activity occurring here is *stream compaction* and thrust provides a [nice set of routines](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html) for various use-cases.  For example this operation could also be done with `thrust::unique_copy()` and in that case, with some additional code complexity, you could eliminate the need for the `thrust::sequence()` call (it would be replaced by a `thrust::counting_iterator` zipped together with your data, and an appropriate selection functor), but it still requires an output vector of the same length.

Comment: Nice! Elegant Solution.

Comment: We tried both solutions, and this one came out a little bit faster

Answer (score 3):

As @tera pointed out, you can compare a number with the previous number to determine whether it is the first occurrence in a sequence of unique number. You can write a kernel to generate a mask for this criteria such that the mask array contains the index for a number which is a first occurrence and a negative number (like -1, as it cannot be an index) otherwise. After that, use thrust to count the non -1 values by using a predicate. Then copy those values from the mask using the same predicate as above. Finally, copy back the results to host.

Here is a sample implementation of the above mentioned approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/count.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

using namespace std;


//Copy index
__global__ void is_first_occurence(int* input, int* is, int count)
{
    const int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if(tid<count)
    {
        if(tid == 0)
        {
            is[0] = 0;
        }
        else if(input[tid] != input[tid-1])
        {
            is[tid] = tid;
        }
        else
        {
            is[tid] = -1;
        }
    }
}


struct isFirst
{
  __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const int x)
  {
    return (x != -1);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int count = 13;

    std::vector<int> arr = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4 ,4 };

    thrust::device_vector<int> arr_d = arr;
    thrust::device_vector<int> mask_d(arr_d.size());

    int* pArr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(arr_d.data() );
    int* pMask = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(mask_d.data() );

    dim3 block(16);
    dim3 grid((count + block.x -1)/block.x);

    is_first_occurence<<<grid,block>>>(pArr, pMask, count);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    int num_unique = thrust::count_if(mask_d.begin(), mask_d.end(), isFirst());

    thrust::copy_if(mask_d.begin(), mask_d.end(), arr_d.begin(), isFirst());

    std::vector<int> unique_indices(num_unique);

    thrust::copy(arr_d.begin(), arr_d.begin() + num_unique, unique_indices.begin());

    for(auto i:unique_indices)
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested using the following command:

> nvcc -o get_unique get_unique.cu -std=c++11 -arch=sm_61